# Android Video Preview Goes blank after stop recording

Tags: android, video-capture

I tried the snippet in this [link](http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/Camcorder.zip).

Recording works fine but the screen goes blank on stop recording. 
I even tried removing recorder.release(); in the stop function but still the screen goes blank.

Kindly help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue but i have not used SurfaceHolder. I have used only intent to call camera and it works fine till the time i give output path to it..

You can try this. just dont provide output path/name to your camera and it will work fine.It will store the video in its default format.